# To show that any compact subgroup of $C^*$ is a subset of unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

> Let $C^*$ denotes the multiplicative group of complex numbers different from zero and $T^*$ be the subgroup of all $z\in C^*$ such that $|z|=1$. Prove that if $G$ is a subgroup of $C^*$ which is compact (as a set of complex numbers), then $G\subset T^*.$

I started to prove it with contradiction but couldn't reach in the result. How can I solve it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Compact implies bounded.

Comment: @anomaly so here we don't have to use $G$ as a closed set,right?

Comment: @mathiu_lady No, but you can use it to continue and show that either $G=T^*$ or $G$ is finite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that it is not contained in $T^*$, there exists $z\in G$ such that $|z|\neq 1$ you have $|z|$ or $|z|^{-1}>1$, if $|z|>1$, $|z|^n$ is not bounded this implies that $G$ is not bounded contradiction since a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is bounded. If $|z|^{-1}>1$, apply the same argument.